# Is it possible to stream to an Android phone with Microsoft Media Server?

Tags: android, stream, multimedia

Let's say that I have Microsoft Media Server stream (i.e. mms://[some ip address here]).  This stream contains both audio and video. Is it possible to stream this to an Android phone?  How would I go about doing this?  Preferably with video, but if it is an audio stream only that would also be okay.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, Microsoft halted support in 08 for MMS. I would dump them and find a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

mms:// is used as placeholder url schema. WMS will stream through either RTSP or HTTP protocols. However in order to playback stream on the phone you need streaming code and codec. Android seems to support WMA/WMV codecs, but I do not see any information about protocols.